# Ansible: obtain a variable from a group of host

Tags: ansible

I have a group of server like:

```
[mygroup]
server1
server2
server3
```

Is there a way in ansible to have a variable that is the result of the concatenation of all hosts in the group mygroup?:

Example:

```
server1:80,server2:80,server3:80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ groups.mygroup|map('regex_replace', '(.*)', '\\1:80')|list|join(',') }}"
```

If I have the hosts `host0`, `host1`, and `host2` in my inventory, this produces:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "host2:80,host1:80,host0:80"
}
```